# How to show CupertinoPicker and select Item after initialization?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna show users Cupertino Picker with selected item when they tap "EDIT" button.

Here is the code I expected that the Cupertino Picker would show the selected item with the index according to the counter how many times user tapped button. But it always shows the picker with initialItem 0.

I know it can be reached if I initialize FixedExtentScrollController with initial item every time user tap "EDIT" button, but I'm curious why my code does not work properly.

Thanks in advance.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isEditing = false;
  int _counter = 0;
  FixedExtentScrollController _controller = FixedExtentScrollController();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void _edit() {
    setState(() {
      _isEditing = !_isEditing;
      _controller.jumpToItem(_counter);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: [
          _isEditing
              ? Text("test")
              : CupertinoPicker(
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (item) => {print(item)},
                  itemExtent: 30,
                  children: [Text('aaa'), Text('bbb'), Text('ccc')],
                  scrollController: _controller,
                ),
          TextButton(onPressed: () => {_edit()}, child: Text("EDIT")),
        ]),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```